# Refresh Query / cxGrid without losing selected record

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I understand that doing the following refreshes a query.

```
query.Close;
query.Open;
```

But after doing this it sets focus back to the very first record on the cxGrid.

Is there a way to make the current record remain selected after refreshing the query?

Thanks.

I have done the following..

```
procedure Tdatamodule.RefreshGrid;
var pos : tbookmark;
begin
pos := qryMainGrid.GetBookmark;
try
  qryMainGrid.Close;
  qryMainGrid.Open;
  qryMainGrid.GotoBookmark(pos);
finally
  qryMainGrid.FreeBookmark(pos);
end;
```

end;

But now get error message **bookmark not found for dataset.**

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Depending on the type of your query component, you can add `if qryMainGrid.BookmarkValid(pos) then` before the call to `GotoBookmark` to stop that error.

Comment: I am using TADquery which is a fireDAC component, I have tried BookmarkValidate(pos) before GoToBookmark but I still get the same error, Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To refresh the dataset call the [`Refresh`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Refresh) method and to remember the dataset cursor position use the bookmark. You query for the bookmark to the current cursor position by calling [`GetBookmark`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.GetBookmark), refresh the dataset and move to the bookmarked position by calling [`GotoBookmark`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.GotoBookmark):

```
var
  Bookmark: TBookmark;
begin
  Bookmark := Query.GetBookmark;
  Query.Refresh;
  Query.GotoBookmark(Bookmark);
end;
```

<sup>You don't need to call [`FreeBookmark`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.FreeBookmark) to free the bookmark in your Delphi version because the [`TBookmark`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TBookmark) type became a dynamic array and as such is managed by the compiler when it goes out of scope of the function.</sup>

Comment: I have made edit to my original question with what i have done and what is now happening, thanks

Comment: @TLama that does make things better thanks, but when I open my form with the cxGrid on it, it displays the very bottom of the grid, I have a lot of records on this grid, is there any way to make it show grid at the top when form opens? Thanks,

Comment: @TLama; I think some things are right on the issue, others could be added in another comment.
Anyway the result is good, we just leave it.
[I will delete this comment later also]. Thanks.